# Adding Colorbox to Orchard CMS

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, orchardcms, colorbox

Newbie question:

I've added the Colorbox Module to my Orchard CMS installation. How do I reference the Colorbox Module and call the colorbox function for a youtube video popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colorbox module? Are you talking about this: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Mod.Colorbox ? Colorbox is now included in Orchards core so you can include it in your view like so:

```
@{
 Script.Require("jQueryColorBox").AtFoot();
 Style.Require("jQueryColorBox").AtHead();
}
```

Check out the colorbox page for demos of opening youtube videos in colorbox: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/